# Show max to min count in SQL group by

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a table with `id, Name` columns.

When selecting I want to `group by` on `Name` column (but show all records NO summary), and show result count max number of in one grouping to min number of one grouping.

```
SELECT Table1.id, Table1.name
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.id, Table1.name;
```

This is table:

[image]

My idea:

[image]

but I get this result:

[image]

Comment: Please explain the ordering in the second `my idea` expected output.

Comment: excuse me edited my idea pic now

Comment: first number  of "Z" is 3, then number of "H" is 2 and number of "R" is 1

Comment: So why is H between Z and R? Why are Z ascending and H descending? What is the logic behind "my idea"?

Comment: my idea edited.

Comment: How does R become 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach uses a join to a subquery which finds the counts for each name:

```
SELECT a.name, a.ID
FROM Table1 AS a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY name
) AS b
    ON a.name = b.name
ORDER BY
    b.cnt DESC,
    a.ID;
```

Comment: ok when i have a condition on ID Field got Error. is possible to have a condition on it?

Comment: for exam INNER JOIN with ```IDs > 2``` Condition

Comment: found it. condition must before ORDER BY

Answer (score 0):

When you group by ID you create a separate group for each element, because each element has a unique ID. To get the count of each name group, you will want to create a grouping by name and then join it with your original table so the values are preserved. Something like:

```
  WITH Counts (name, cnt) AS
       (SELECT name, COUNT(*)
          FROM Table1
         GROUP BY name)
SELECT Table1.id, Table1.name
  FROM Table1, Counts
       INNER JOIN Counts
       ON Table1.name = Counts.name
 ORDER BY Counts.cnt DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I see.  You an use a subquery in the `order by`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.name = t.name) desc, name;
```

Note that `name` is the second `order by` key.  If two names have the same counts, then this keeps all the rows for a given name together.